# integration yields different values if done by parts or by substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

If you compute the integral:
$$ \int \frac{2x}{(x+1)^2}.$$ by substitution (using $u=x+1$, then you
will get.

$$ 2 \ln | 1 + x | + \frac{2}{1+x} + C.$$

But if, instead, you use integration by parts: $u=x, dv=2/(1+x)^2$, you will get

$$ -\frac{2x}{1+x} + 2 \ln | 1 +x | + C .$$

Clearly $C$ cannot depend on $x$. The two results should be the same.

Why are they different?

Comment: The answers are in fact equivalent.

Comment: @AdamRubinson : I do not see that. Could you please explain?

Comment: $$\frac{2}{1+x}=2-\frac{2x}{1+x}$$

Comment: This is a good illustration of why I think indefinite integrals should be banned. Especially the formula for the indefinite integral of $1/x$. You never see indefinite integrals in any setting after Calculus 2, not even in Calculus 3. You do use an antiderivative when using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but you need only one specific one, no $+C$ needed. It's the definite integral that matters, and all of the attention should be focused on that. Then there's no need to figure out what exactly "+C$ means.

Comment: @Deane The name "indefinite integral" is lousy: that must be called, imo, antiderivative. And we use it *a lot* after Cals. 2: to evaluate definite (Riemann) integrals, say.

Comment: @DonAntonio, an indefinite integral is not an antiderivative. It is a misguided attempt to represent *all* antiderivatives. I did mention the use of *an* antiderivative for the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: @Deane It is **exactly** THE ANTIDERIVATIVE (or (all) the antiderivatives if you will)...which is this weird being, not a function at all, that represents each and every function that is an antiderivative of the integrand function.

Answer (score 2):

The difference  of the two functions you get (with different $\;C\;$ each) is:

$$2\log|1+x|+\frac2{1+x}+C-\left(-\frac{2x}{1+x}+2\log|1+x|+C'\right)=$$

$$=\frac{2+2x}{1+x}+\overbrace{K}^{=C-C'}=2+K=\text{ a constant}$$

and thus both of them are a primitive function of $\;\cfrac{2x}{(1+x)^2}\;$ .

Comment: That is right. I did not think on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not a function. It is a collection of functions. You can think of it as a list of functions. Each different value of $C$ is a solution (a member of the list). The two solutions look different, but they give the same collection of functions. If you write $2\ln|1+x|+\frac{2}{1+x}+C_1$ and $\frac{-2x}{1+x}+2\ln|1+x|+C_2$, you can set these equal and solve. That is, for each $C_1$ in the first function, you'll get a $C_2$ in the second function, and vice versa. But the constants won't be the same.

If you think about $C$ as one number, it looks confusing. But if you remember that $C$ ranges over all values, you'll see that you get the same list.

Comment: In your second expression, you have $-2/(1+x)$, while the OP is saying it is $-2x/(1+x)$.

Comment: @jwhite  : First, one is $2/(1+x)$ and the other $-2x/(1+x).$ If you dump those into C1 and C2, you would get something like $C_2 = C_1 + 2/(1+x) + 2x/(1+x)$ and $C_2$ depends on $x$. That cannot happen.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo $\frac{2}{1+x}+\frac{2x}{1+x}=\frac{2(1+x)}{1+x}=2$ doesn't depend on $x$.

Comment: @Doug Thanks for spotting that. I've corrected it.

Comment: @jwhite : you are correct. I failed to see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$ -\frac{2x}{1+x} = \frac{-2x}{1+x}  = \frac{-2x-2+2}{1+x} = \frac{-2(1+x)}{1+x} + \frac{2}{1+x} = -2 + \frac{2}{1+x}.$$